# DataTable con id's dinámicos

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

Estoy usando el plugin DataTables de `jQuery` con `HTML`, `php` y `MySQL`. Si construyo una tabla y utilizo el plugin funciona todo correcto, el problema aparece cuando quiero crear múltiples tablas y que éstas sean DataTables. Quizá con el código quede más claro. Lo dejo abajo.

DataTable funcionando:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none" id="datatable-tabletools">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 60px; text-align: center;">Id</th>
          <th style="width: 400px; text-align: center;">Info A</th>
          <th style="width: 390px; text-align: center;">Info B</th>
          <th style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">Actions</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <!-- tbody dynamically populated -->
      </tbody>
    </table>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#datatable-tabletools').DataTable({
         });
       });
     </script>
```

DataTable no funcionando:

```
<?php
foreach ($sections as $section)
{
   $insc = Inscripciones::getAllInscriptionBySection($section -> getId());
   if (count($insc) > 0)
   {
     ?>
     <h2 style="margin-bottom: 50px;"><?php echo $section->getNombre(); ?></h2>
     <table class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-none" id="datatable-tabletools-<?php echo $section -> getId(); ?>">
       <thead>
         <tr>
           <th style="width: 60px; text-align: center;">Id</th>
           <th style="width: 450px; text-align: center;">Category</th>
           <th style="width: 390px; text-align: center;">Title</th>
           <th style="width: 140; text-align: center;">Usuario</th>
           <th style="width: 100px; text-align: center;">Acciones</th>
         </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         <!-- tbody also dynamically populated -->
       </tbody>
     </table>
  <?php
  }
}
  ?>



    <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#datatable-tabletools-1').DataTable({
           });
           $('#datatable-tabletools-2').DataTable({
           })
           $('#datatable-tabletools-3').DataTable({
           })
          });
   </script>
```

Lo más curioso es que en el código fuente renderizado aparecen los id's como "datatable-tabletools-1", "datatable-tabletools-2" etc
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Qué error recibes?¿Cómo no funciona?

Comment: Hola. Necesitas implementar configuraciones diferentes para cada tabla? Si no lo necesitas puedes ponerles a todas la misma clase y referenciarlas con $('.claseComun').DataTable({}); y se aplicará para todas.

Comment: Hola y gracias por la respuesta! No recibo ningún error, tan sólo printa las tablas como tablas estándar

Comment: Hola! ya he provado también con clases pero sin suerte...

Comment: Yo lo acabo de probar localmente y funcionó perfectamente. Si no tienes configuraciones diferentes para cada tabla referencíalas con una clase en común. Dime ¿Necesitas configuraciones distintas para cada tabla?

Comment: @user2930137, he probado usar una clase y no me ha funcionado, viendo que a ti sí voy a volver a probar y a darle una vuelta a ver que tal, tan sólo has copiado el código y te ha funcionado?

Comment: No has contestado mi pregunta. No he copiado el código pues estás usando php con variables y obviamente no tengo su valor. Si no necesitas configuraciones diferentes debería bastar con el código que te pondré como respuesta.

Comment: @user2930137 no, no necesito configuraciones distintas para las diferentes tablas

Comment: Tu código me funciona sin problemas y DataTables se aplica correctamente ([ver en JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g4jush1n/)). El problema que tienes puede ocurrir por diferentes motivos: porque no estés cargando DataTables correctamente: o porque `datatable-tabletools-<?php echo $section -> getId();` no devuelva lo que tu crees que devuelve (personalmente, no sé por qué tienes los `id`s escritos a fuerza en lugar de guardarlos en una variable o algo, podría darse el caso de que no estés aplicando DataTables a todas las tablas por eso)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes referenciarlas por una clase en común si no necesitas configuraciones dataTable() diferentes para cada tabla.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function () {
           $('.table').DataTable({ });

          });
   </script>
```

Eso debería funcionar perfectamente, dime ¿No lo hace?

Comment: Lo he provado y no funciona

Comment: @Icar Gongora, podrías intentar así, por favor:
window.onload = function() {
     $('.hola').DataTable({});
 };

Comment: he provado con clases en un script nuevo y ha funcionado por lo que entiendo que tengo que estar fallando por algún otro lado, te valido la respuesta puesto que en un script limpio (sólo con la tabla) ha funcionado

Comment: No me interesa que valides mi respuesta con algo que no te sirvió. Es interesante tu caso y quiero saber por qué no lo toma con tu código. No es por ti, es por mí ahora jhahaha. Dime, intentaste con window.onload?